# verify existence of rows in table and update

Tags: java, sql, insert-update

I want to update rows where that row's ID exists in a table, and insert a new row if the ID doesn't exist in the table. For this have the below code to attempt to verify each row's existance in the table, but it doesn't work for me. The code always reports that the row exists, and my code always inserts a new row (instead of updating when the row already exists):

```
String sqlVerif="select * from calcul where idproduit="+codeP+" and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)="+MonthStock;
         ResultSet duplicateExists =stmt.executeQuery(sqlVerif);
         System.out.println(duplicateExists);

         if(duplicateExists.next()){
             System.out.println("je suis ici update");
             String sqlUpdate="UPDATE calcul set inventaire="+(this.GetInventaire(codeP))+(quantite)+",quantite="+this.GetQuantiteStock(codeP)+(quantite)+" where idproduit="+codeP+" and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)="+MonthStock;
             stmt.executeUpdate(sqlUpdate);

         }


         else{
              System.out.println("je suis ici insert");
         String sql1="INSERT INTO calcul (idproduit,inventaire,consomation,date,quantite,designation) "
               + "VALUES ('"+codeP+"',"+newQuant+","+0+",'"+datestock+"',"+newQuant+",'"+designation+"' );";

           stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
         }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant tag for the database you are using. Note: the operation you are looking for is usually referred to as an "UPSERT". Try searching for that.

Comment: If by "_i get always existence result_" you mean that your `System.out.println(duplicateExists)` always prints out something instead of `null`, that's because an empty `ResultSet` object is not `null`. Otherwise based on how your code is designed if it's detected that rows exist then the update would be executed, not the insert.
I suggest to straighten up your question; also, I'd print out the value of your `sqlVerif` string and execute it _exactly as is_ against your db directly, through a db client, to make sure it returns what you expect.

Comment: thank you it's work
String sql = "INSERT INTO stock (idproduit,quantite,datestock, designation,dateper,ppa,tr,net) "
               + "VALUES ('"+codeP+"', "+quantite+",'"+datestock+"','"+designation+"','"+datePer+"',"+PPA+","+TR+","+NET+" );";
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);